# Advantages Of Putting HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering if it is better to put your html in javascript or in your html files.

For example having my js file have this

```
$('<div>').addClass('test').append(
                        $('<p>').text('test1'),
                        $('<span>').text('test2'),
                        $('<span>').text('test3')
                      ).insertAfter( $('#test1') );
```

VS

My html file looking like this

```
<div id="#test1"></div>
<div class="test">
    <p>test1</p>
    <span>test2</span>
    <span>test3</span>
</div>
```

and the js file have:

$('.test').show();

Comment: The general idea is to separate your logic and markup as much as possible. In this case the first option makes little sense and pollutes your javascript, plus performance will be worse because you're creating every element.

Comment: You can (sort-of) get the best of both worlds via a JavaScript template system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly subjective and depends on contexts of course.

In a web page, most of the content is already known.  No reason not to just put the content in the HTML and use CSS (and maybe Javascript when really needed) to style in.

In a web application, however, things are *not* so well known.  The document is much more dynamic and using Javascript to add/remove elements is required.

*BTW, your two pieces of code do two different things.  In the first example you give it a `class` of `test` and in the second you are giving it an `ID` of `#test1`.  This is an invalid `ID` and should be `test1`.  The `selector` for that ID would be `#test1` which may be causing some of the confusion.*

Answer (score 1):

This is probably okay for just straight-up webpages, but for web applications you should really look into a templating system such as `mustache.js`(https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) or `Handlebars.js`(http://handlebarsjs.com/).

That way, you can keep your HTML in external template files and use `Javascript` objects and arrays to fill them with data. For example, a mustache template might look like:

```
<div id="{{id}}"></div>
<div class="{{class}}">
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <span>{{prop1}}</span>
    <span>{{prop2}}</span>
</div>
```

And you would have an object that looks like this to fill it:

```
var obj = {
    id: "myID",
    class: "some classes",
    name: "Martin Brennan",
    prop1: "whatever",
    prop2: 22
}
```

And you would use the template with the object like this (after loading the template into a variable):

```
Mustache.render(template, obj)
```

Like Jeremy J Starcher said though, this is highly subjective, and I would suggested that you give templating systems a try to see if you can see the value in using them in your project(s).

Answer (score 0):

Of course the second option is much better and faster.

If you use

```
$('<div>').addClass('test').append(
                        $('<p>').text('test1'),
                        $('<span>').text('test2'),
                        $('<span>').text('test3')
                      ).insertAfter( $('#test1') );
```

browser must parse JavaScript. And each time you use `$()` you are creating an object which has a lot of properties and methods which you don't use (useless!). And of course the browser must parse the HTML too.

But if you use

```
<div id="#test1"></div>
<div class="test">
    <p>test1</p>
    <span>test2</span>
    <span>test3</span>
</div>
```

browser only has to parse HTML and it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

One of the largest benefits of using the 2nd, hard-coded HTML method is that it'll still show up for people with JavaScript disabled. It's hard to verify exactly how many users don't have JS enabled (because most trackers use JS..) but last guesstimate I heard was somewhere around 5% of internet users.

Moral of the story - make your site work without JavaScript. Then and only then add JavaScript to make it look prettier/ add additional (non essential) features.

Comment: maybe for static sites but say for web apps - twitter, for instance tells you straight out that you cannot even use it at all without js enabled. Imagine if twitter were not allowed to use JS because of the very rare case of js being disabled or not existing - maybe it wouldnt exist or would definitely not be the same experience without js! JS is, thank goodness, pretty much assumed now. Soon, likewise, IE will be assumed as nonexistent, which is actually not a bad idea to do anyway these days (just few years ago, was still for some reason a big big deal to have to support IE, not so much now)

Comment: I was curious and checked it out myself. Twitter (and Facebook and Google) work exactly as one would expect a non-JS site to work: they give you a warning that you're missing out, but then show you the content anyways. They are, of course limited to updating tweets, search results, etc on page refresh (I miss ajax already), but the basis is the sites work without JS. JS does enhance your experience, but it doesn't need to limit their's.

Also, I doubt IE is going away anytime soon. IE6 & IE7, sure. Not IE8+ though for a while.

Comment: hmm maybe they changed it or maybe I am mistaken...I swear about a year or two ago, I was not allowed to log into twitter without having js enabled, it said I simply could not log in at all unless I enable js. Could have been that I thought the allowed usage was so limited that i considered it nonfunctional, though I was pretty sure it said *required* js - I have a feeling I am mistaken and you are right tho - good that you checked it out! It's not that IE is going away, but it used to be majority so you had to support it - now, it is Chrome who used to be at 1% is now the majority browser!

Comment: It looks like the mobile site is non functional without JS - maybe that's what you saw? Chrome... It's so simple and so effective. For me, it's even replaced FireFox for normal web browsing (although I'm still partial to FireBug in FF over Chrome's developer tools).

Comment: That might have been it. I like chrome better as well. Though I use both - only Chrome Developer tools for instance can actually see the frames transferred for websockets connection. Firefox I like Firebug way better sometimes because of the DOM panel and sometimes the errors are actually a little better in terms of inding root cause faster for me. Chrome console I usually like better than Firebug's though - so I usually use both Firebug and CWT . For browsing Chrome is faster and better. Even Safari or Opera I like better than Firefox for plain vanilla browsing

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that static content should be created using normal markup, while Javascript should be used for dynamic content.

Also, in many cases you can use both. You can have static HTML markup with `style="display:none"`, and then use Javascript to change the style to make it appear and disappear as needed.